# Class Cast Exception in Android

Tags: android, listview, classcastexception, android-relativelayout

I'm making an android application with a navigation drawer. I also want to display a transparent instruction screen the first time the user opens the app. For this, I have a relative Layout in my xml file, and a listView for the drawer.

XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.twistedlines.overbudget.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <!-- transparent overlay -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#77CCCCCC" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/transparent_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contdesc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/instructions" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:divider="#c7c7c7"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"></ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However, I'm getting a classCastException in my java file in this line:

```
drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
```

Logcat:

> 11-11 00:10:53.417: E/test(8163): Exception 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.twistedlines.overbudget/com.twistedlines.overbudget.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.ListView 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-11 00:10:53.437:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8163): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ListView 11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):
>     at
>   com.twistedlines.overbudget.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:118)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 11-11
>   00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   11-11 00:10:53.437: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)

It says RelativeLayout cannot be cast ti ListView. But in my XML, drawerList is a ListView, not a RelativeLayout. What is the problem?

My drawerList variable is a ListView object. Here is the declaration:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ListView drawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle abdToggle;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_transparent);



           if (isFirstTime()) {
                topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);   //exception line
        adaptr=new mAdapter(this);
        drawerList.setAdapter(adaptr);
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new itemListener());
        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Overview");

       //rest of the code
```

Comment: Where is drawerList first defined?

Comment: Clean and rebuild if you're 100% sure that you are referring to the correct ids.

Comment: You don't happen to have multiple layout folders do you? If you do, you might have that id being used as a relative layout in the folder that the app is choosing. I would do a quick ctrl+shift+f for drawerList to see if it is in another layout file.

Comment: Cleaning the project worked. Thank you. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems alright to me. Just try to clean and rebuilt it again.

For Cleaning. 
Go to  **Project -> Clean** . Select your project and click **ok**.

To rebuilt it again, just run your code.